# Поиск и замена байтов на Python

Tags: python

Мне нужно в HEX файле найти значения [0x00, 0x07, 0x77, 0x77, 0x77, 0x77, 0x77, 0x77, 0x77, 0x77, 0x77, 0x77, 0x77, 0x77, 0x77, 0x77]

Потом нужно отступить назад на 15 байт, а затем проверить, если строчка равна 0x00, то заменить нужно ее на 0x01.

Небольшой код уже накидал в питоне:

```
import sys
bait = ["\x01"]
f = open("yourfile.txt",'rb')
bdbuf = bytearray( f.read() )
x = f.read()
bdL = len(bdbuf)
print(bdL)
if b"\x00\x07\x77\x77\x77\x77\x77\x77\x77\x77\x77\x77\x77\x77\x77\x77" in bdbuf:
    for i in x:
        a=-15
        new = bait[a]=i
        f.write(new)
else:
    print('Error')
```

Comment: если вы работаете в бинарном файле, то о каких строчках идет речь? что является индикатором конца строки и началом новой?

Comment: Я хочу создать скрипт на пайтоне, чтобы он находил нужные байты [0x00, 0x07, 0x77, 0x77, 0x77, 0x77, 0x77, 0x77, 0x77, 0x77, 0x77, 0x77, 0x77, 0x77, 0x77, 0x77] отступал от них 15 байт, а затем проверял, если байт равен = 0х00, то его нужно заменить на 0х01.

Comment: ваш код проверяет наличие нужной последовательности в считаной строке и после этого делает что-то непонятное. Вы даже не получаете позицию, где эта строка находится. Что вы хотите получить от bait[-15], если в bait лежит один элемент?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я предполагаю, что переместиться на 15 байт назад вам нужно, чтобы заменить первый байт последовательности, поэтому просто ищем начало этой последовательности и заменяем байт в ее начале

```
# Открыть файл в бинарном режиме для чтения и записи
with open("file.bin", "rb+") as file:
    # Прочитать файл полностью
    data = file.read()
    # Найти индекс, с которого начинается искомая последовательность
    i = data.find(b"\x00\x07\x77\x77\x77\x77\x77\x77\x77\x77\x77\x77\x77\x77\x77\x77")
    if i == -1:
        print("Последовательность не найдена")
    else:
        # Переместиться в файле на начало последовательности
        file.seek(i)
        # Перезаписать первый байт этой последовательности
        file.write(b"\x01")
```

Для больших файлов чтение файлов в память полностью - это не очень оптимально (в таких случаях лучше читать файл блоками), но для небольших файлов это вполне допустимо.

Вариант с чтением по блокам:

```
needle = b"\x00\x07\x77\x77\x77\x77\x77\x77\x77\x77\x77\x77\x77\x77\x77\x77"

with open("file.bin", "rb+") as file:
    prev_block = b''
    prev_block_start = 0

    # Читаем блоками размером в искомую последовательность
    for block in iter(lambda: file.read(len(needle)), b''):  
        # Ищем последовательность в двух смежных блоках
        # (чтобы учесть случаи, когда она переходит через границу считанного блока)
        i = (prev_block + block).find(needle)
        if i >= 0:
            # Последовательность найдена
            file.seek(prev_block_start + i)
            file.write(b"\x01")
            break
        
        prev_block_start += len(prev_block)
        prev_block = block
    else:
        print("Последовательность не найдена")
```

---

Пример со множественной заменой (по первому варианту, т.е. с чтением файла в память полностью):

```
needle = b"\x00\x07\x77\x77\x77\x77\x77\x77\x77\x77\x77\x77\x77\x77\x77\x77"

with open("file.bin", "rb+") as file:
    data = file.read()
    
    i = 0
    while True:
        i = data.find(needle, i)
        if i == -1:
            break
        
        file.seek(i - 15)
        if file.peek(1) != b"\x01":  # peek аналогично read, но не изменяет текущую позицию в файле
            file.write(b"\x01")

        i += 1
```

---

Еще дополню. Есть смысл разделить поиск и замену, например вынести поиск в отдельную функцию, потом замену делать по списку найденных позиций искомого набора байт:

```
# Поиск с загрузкой файла целиком
def find_all(file, needle):
    i = file.tell()  # Определить текущую позицию в файле
    data = file.read()
    while True:
        i = data.find(needle, i)
        if i == -1:
            break
        
        yield i
        
        i += 1


# Поиск с загрузкой файла блоками
def find_all_2(file, needle):
    prev_block = b''
    prev_block_start = file.tell()
    
    for block in iter(lambda: file.read(len(needle)), b''):
        i = (prev_block + block).find(needle)
        if i >= 0:
            yield prev_block_start + i
        
        prev_block_start += len(prev_block)
        prev_block = block


# Замена байт будет выглядеть одинаково, т.к. у функций поиска одинаковый "интерфейс"
needle = b"\x00\x07\x77\x77\x77\x77\x77\x77\x77\x77\x77\x77\x77\x77\x77\x77"


with open("file.bin", "rb+") as file:
    # для поиска с загрузкой блоками заменить вызов find_all на find_all_2
    positions = list(find_all(file, needle)) 
    for i in positions:
        file.seek(i - 15)
        if file.peek(1) != b"\x01":
            file.write(b"\x01")
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное! Только вот нужно, чтобы он искал начало этой последовательности и от нее отступал 15 байт. А так просто получается, он изменяет первый байт

Comment: Ну тогда там где `file.seek` делайте `file.seek(i - 15)`, тогда будет отступать назад на 15 байт (правда желательно проверять, чтобы результат не получился отрицательным, иначе будет ошибка). Все остальное остается без изменений.

Comment: Все, спасибо огромное!

Comment: А не подскажите как проверять, есть ли там 0x00 или он уже заменен на 0x01

Comment: Что, то вроде   buffer = file.seek(i - 15)
        if buffer != b'\x00':
         file.write(b"\x01")
        else:
         print('File already fine!')

Comment: Переместиться с помощью seek, прочитать один байт с помощью file.read(1), сравнить, потом опять переместиться на i - 15 (при чтении одного байта сместились на один байт вперед, поэтому нужно вернуться обратно), записать байт.

Comment: Спасибо, а если файле несколько таких значений. Можно найти все и в каждой заменить значение?

Comment: Ну, можно в цикле все найденные позиции добавлять в список, потом циклом пройтись по этому списку и позаменять.

Comment: У меня есть код, на c, я хочу его перевести на пайтон. Может я напишу вам код, а вам будет легче меня понять?

Comment: string filePath = args[0];
if (File.Exists(filePath))
       {
byte[] inputbd = File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);
fixbd(inputbd, filePath);
                }
            }
static void fixbd(byte[] bd, string path)
{
byte[] bdendline = {0x00, 0x07, 0x77, 0x77, 0x77, 0x77, 0x77, 0x77, 0x77, 0x77, 0x77, 0x77, 0x77, 0x77, 0x77, 0x77};
bool match;
int flagsInserted = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < bd.Length; i++)
{
if(i == bd.Length -1)
{
break;
}
if(bd[i] == bdendline[0])
{
match = true;
for (int j = 1; j <= bdendline.Length - 1; j++)
{

Comment: if (bd[i + j] != bdendline[j])
{ match = false; break;}     }
     if (match && bd[i-15] == 0x00)
     {
      bd[i-15] = 0x01;
      flagsInserted++;
      Console.WriteLine("Flag inserted");
     }
}
} if (flagsInserted == 0)
{
Console.WriteLine("No missing flags found, this file should be fine.");
Console.WriteLine("Press enter to close....");
Console.ReadLine();
}
else
{
File.WriteAllBytes(path + "fix", bd);
Console.WriteLine("Finished. " + flagsInserted.ToString() + " flags inserted");
Console.WriteLine("Press enter to close....");
Console.ReadLine();
}
}
}
}

Comment: Не надо так делать, комментарии не предназначены для размещения больших блоков кода.

Comment: Я сейчас добавлю пример со множественной заменой, если он не подойдет, то задайте отдельный вопрос с полным кодом, который вы пытаетесь перевести и вашими попытками.

Comment: Спасибо, помогло, все работает